# Overwrite options for bootstrap datepicker

Tags: jquery, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

I have define a generic options for all datepickers of my site in a js file, now I am trying to update/overwrite specific field through id, but I am unable to achieve it.

```
 **HTML**
 <input id="mydate" class="datepick" type="text">

 **JS**
 $('.datepick').datepicker({
     autoclose: true,
     todayHighlight: true,
     /* startDate: '+1m'  This option will work here*/
 });

  $('#mydate').datepicker({
     startDate: '+1m' /* But it doesnt work here*/
 });
```

Here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/LT7qE/90/

Comment: Your code *should* work.  Seems like a bug in the library

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `setStartDate` to set start date after datepicker was initialized

Here's [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LT7qE/91/)

```js
 $('.datepick').datepicker({
     autoclose: true,
     todayHighlight: true,
     /* startDate: '+1m'  This option will work here*/
 });
 
  $('#mydate').datepicker('setStartDate','+1m');
```

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.2.0/css/datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.2.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<input id="mydate" class="datepick" type="text">
```

Comment: Great it works, but what If the options are multiple ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/LT7qE/92/ you need to repeat it `$('#mydate').datepicker('setStartDate','+1m').datepicker('setEndDate','+2m');` and more about methods that can be change without reinitializing datepicker: http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/methods.html